# Average of the cells of a column after multiplying them with cells from other column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, formula

How can I perform this calculation (something like AVERAGEPRODUCT) and make it work? I want to calculate the sum the cells of column Z after multiplying them with the cells of column AC and then divide them with the last cell of column AC. I am sorry for providing so few data but literally, the only thing I need is a working method to perform the line of code below. The line is really messed up . sorry for that.

Picture!

[image]

```
.Range("Z" & i & ").Formula = "=SUM((Z2:Z" & cnt + 1 & ")*(AC2:AC" & cnt + 1 & ")/Range("AC" & i))"
```

Answer (score 1):

The worksheet function might look something like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(AVERAGE(A1:A3*B1:B3))
```

With VBA you could use something like this instead:

```
Range("C1").Value = Evaluate("=Average(A1:A3*B1:B3)")
```

---

For you:

```
.Range("Z" & i).Value = Evaluate("=AVERAGE(Z2:Z" & cnt + 1 & "*AC2:AC" & cnt + 1 & ")")
```

Comment: A ok! great! and how can I make it work with ranges like its on my code?

Comment: And to be more clear, I want first the multiplications to be executed and then find the average of these new values

Comment: I dont want to sum the averages, I want to find the average of all the cells after they are multiplied

Comment: Both of these functions work as your are explaining - the `SUMPRODUCT` is actually only summing one number. It's there to ensure the `AVERAGE` is treated as an array formula -- meaning each average is calculated separately. I'll add another example which works exactly for you.

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas, example added.

Comment: it prints a result but it is not the correct result! I will upload a screenshot of my worksheet for you to see how it looks. Now the percentage is way above the normal one. The reason I want to multiply these columns is because if I calculate the average only for cells in column Z , as you can see the result will not be the accurate one, as the first two cells are supposed to be muliple ones(6 and 8), but after the consolidation I performed, they are consolidated as one. So, the result is not correct. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: The average should be 91,1%

Comment: I actually figured the mistake out.. Is it possible to provide me with the exact code for SUMPRODUCT? If I perform the sumproduct after the multiplication, then I can devide with the last cell of column AC as seen on the screenshot and get the result! thanks for your help either way man!

Comment: You are calculating a weighted average of the values in column `Z` using  the corresponding values in column `AC` as weights. The formula you want is `=SUMPRODUCT(Z2:Z9,AC2:AC9)/SUM(AC2:AC9)` and the result using the data in your question is 86.76%